# How to dynamically reverse the bit position in verilog?

Tags: verilog

```
wire [9:0] data_reg;
reg [3:0] Reverse_Count = 8;  //This register is derived in logic and I need to use it in following logic in order to reverse the bit position. 
assign data_reg[9:0] = 10'h88;  // Data Register

genvar i;
for (i=0; i< Reverse_Count; i=i+1) 
   assign IReg_swiz[i] = IReg[Reverse_Count - 1 -i];
```

This is generating syntax error.  May I know how to do this in verilog

Comment: It is good practice to include the actual error in the question. if you could please edit and include. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd have `Reverse_Count` as constant, your task boils down to just wire mix-up, which is essentially free in HDL.
In your case, the task can be nicely reduced to first mirroring wide data and then shifting by `Reverse_Count` to get LBS bit on its position, which itself is done just by a row of N-to-1 multiplexers.

```
integer i;
reg  [9:0] reversed;
wire [9:0] result;

// mirror bits in wide 10-bit value    
always @*
for(i=0;i<10;i=i+1)
    reversed[i] = data_reg[9-i];

// settle LSB on its place
assign result = reversed>>(10-Reverse_Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Reverse_Count` is not a constant, ie it is not a `parameter` or `localparam`.

This means that the generate statement you would be creating and destroying hardware as required, this is not allowed in verilog as it would not be possible in hardware.

The Bus that your reversing should have a fixed width at compile time, it should be possible to declare Reverse_Count as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `Reverse_Count` dunamic, you cannot use a generate statement. You can use an always block with for-loop. To be synthesizable, the for-loop needs able to static unroll. To decide which bits reverse, use an if condition to compare the indexing value and `Reverse_Count`

Example:

```
parameter MAX = 10;
reg [MAX-1:0] IReg_swiz;
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i=0; i < MAX ; i=i+1) begin
    if (i < Reverse_Count) begin
       IReg_swiz[i] = IReg[Reverse_Count - 1 -i];
    end
    else begin
       // All bits need to be assigned or complex latching logic will be inferred.
       IReg_swiz[i] = IReg[i]; // Other values okay depending on your requirements.
    end
  end 
end
```